# ActiveRecord producing double messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scaffold

this code generated by scaffold ends up printing the same message twice and i can't get it to stop.

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @indi.update(indi_params)
        puts("message about to be shown to us by the system")
        format.html { redirect_to @indi, notice: 'Indi was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @indi }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @indi.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

it prints the success message twice in the web page.

Comment: in your webpage view are you rendering the notice twice

Comment: not on purpose.  here is some console output from the server.                   message about to be shown to us by the system
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/indis/48
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/indis/48" ...
Processing by IndisController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"48"}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM 
  Indi Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "indis".* FROM "indis" WHERE "indis"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 48]...
  Rendering indis/show.html.erb w/in layouts/application
  Rendered indis/show.html.erb w/iin layouts/application

Comment: <body>   [this code found in application.html.erb 
  <% if notice %>
    <p class="alert alert-success"><%= notice %></p>
  <% end %>
  <% if alert %>
    <p class="alert alert-danger"><%= alert %></p>
  <% end %>

    <%= yield %>
  </body>

Comment: top of view has  <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

Comment: so you are doing it twice, right. I see it in alert-success as well as _top of view_. isn't that the issue for double rendering?

Comment: i do see code about notices in application.html.erb as well as my view show.html.erb . maybe relevant?

Comment: i think you are on to something

Comment: yes, it is. Do it at one place. Do it in application.html.erb alone since showing notice is general thing, to be shared across views.

Comment: thank you so much that worked! (new to Rails)

Comment: sure. glad to help

Answer (score 1):

To close the question:

Problem was in double rendering in the layout as well as view. He had:

```
<body>
  <% if notice %>
    <p class="alert alert-success"><%= notice %></p>
  <% end %>
  <% if alert %>
    <p class="alert alert-danger"><%= alert %></p>
  <% end %> 
  <%= yield %> 
</body>
```

and in top of `show.html.erb`:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
```

This resulted in double display of `notice`. Fix was to simply remove from `show.html.erb` and to have that in layout. Layout enables such code to be re-used